# Limits for SOQL INNER QUERY in Apex

Tags: salesforce, apex, soql, inner-query

I'm using this query for select records, filter them and then insert another custom record for this object, someone like this (C):

**SELECT Name, Custom_Object__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT Opportunity__c FROM Custom_Object__c)**

So when I select and after insert new Custom_Object__c for Opportunity i'm use standard Limits and see them after run.

In this case, in Production i'm have a 10 000 Opportunities and i'm need to insert about ~10 new Custom_Object__c for each Opp.

And question is: when i'm have 50 000 Custom_Object__c records - can i retrieve new Opportunities with this query, or once the limit in **(SELECT Opportunity__c FROM Custom_Object__c)** is reached, new records will not be added to the main query?

When i'm run this query with exist Custom_Object__c I don't see them in console with TOTAL LIMITS.
Anybody know what limit for this case with? Is it separate or like with subquery we can't see them?

Can't see LIMITs for query. What is limit for this case